# DNS not working with Ipv6

Tags: ubuntu, networking, domain-name-system, bind, ipv6

I'm trying to configure bind for ipv6 protocol.I have added the entries to the zone and configuration files but still the ipv6 IPs are not returned when i try for nslookup.Can someone guide me to correct the configuration files?

/etc/bind/zones/db.10 file

```
    ;
    ; BIND reverse data file for local loopback interface
    ;
    $TTL    604800
    @       IN      SOA     necopdnsone.necthree.com. root.necthree.com. (
                                  3         ; Serial
                             604800         ; Refresh
                              86400         ; Retry
                            2419200         ; Expire
                             604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
    ; NS records
            IN  NS  necopdnsone.necthree.com.
            IN  NS  necopdnstwo.necthree.com.

    129   IN  PTR gateway.necthree.com.
    132   IN  PTR necopdnsone.necthree.com.
    133   IN  PTR necopdnstwo.necthree.com.
    131   IN  PTR necopdhcp.necthree.com.
    135   IN  PTR necopsegw.necthree.com.
```

/etc/bind/zones/db6.ip6.10

```
 ;
    ; BIND reverse data file for local loopback interface
    ;
    $TTL    604800
    @       IN      SOA     necopdnsone.necthree.com. root.necthree.com. (
                                  3         ; Serial
                             604800         ; Refresh
                              86400         ; Retry
                            2419200         ; Expire
                             604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
    ; NS records
            IN  NS  necopdnsone.necthree.com.
            IN  NS  necopdnstwo.necthree.com.

    1.0.0.0   IN  PTR gateway.necthree.com.
    8.0.0.0   IN  PTR necopdnsone.necthree.com.
    9.0.0.0   IN  PTR necopdnstwo.necthree.com.
    7.0.0.0   IN  PTR necopdhcp.necthree.com.
    6.0.0.0   IN  PTR necopsegw.necthree.com.
```

/etc/bind/zones/db.necthree.com

```
;
; BIND data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     necopdnstwo.necthree.com. root.necthree.com. (
                              4         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
; NS records
        IN  NS  necopdnsone.necthree.com.
        IN  NS  necopdnstwo.necthree.com.
; A records
necopdnsone.necthree.com.      IN  A   10.222.190.132
necopdnsone.necthree.com.      IN  AAAA   2001:1:1:3::8
necopdnstwo.necthree.com.      IN  A   10.222.190.133
necopdnstwo.necthree.com.      IN  AAAA   2001:1:1:3::9
necopdhcp.necthree.com.        IN  A   10.222.190.131
necopdhcp.necthree.com.        IN  AAAA   2001:1:1:3::7
necopsegw.necthree.com.        IN  A   10.222.190.135
necopsegw.necthree.com.        IN  AAAA   2001:1:1:3::6
   ;@               IN  A   127.0.0.1
   ;@               IN  AAAA    ::1
gateway           IN  A    10.222.190.129
gateway           IN  AAAA   2001:1:1:3::1
;gaia              IN  A   10.222.190.60
www       IN  CNAME   necthree.com.
```

named.conf.local

```
//
// Do any local configuration here
//

// Consider adding the 1918 zones here, if they are not used in your
// organization
//include "/etc/bind/zones.rfc1918";

zone "necthree.com" {
  type master;
  file "/etc/bind/zones/db.necthree.com";
};
zone "190.222.10.in-addr.arpa" {
  type master;
  file "/etc/bind/zones/db.10";
};
zone "0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.3.0.0.0.1.0.0.0.1.0.0.0.1.0.0.2.ip6.arpa" {
  type master;
  file "/etc/bind/zones/db.ip6.10";
};
```

nslookup output

```
root@ubuntu:/etc/bind# nslookup gateway.necthree.com
Server:         127.0.0.1
Address:        127.0.0.1#53

Name:   gateway.necthree.com
Address: 10.222.190.129
```

Comment: Can you try forcing nslookup to do an AAAA lookup and see if it fails or if nslookup is trying A lookup only.

nslookup -type=aaaa gateway.necthree.com

Comment: I got the same response.root@necopdnsone:~# nslookup -type==aaaa gateway.necthree.com
unknown query type: =aaaa
Server:         10.222.190.132
Address:        10.222.190.132#53

Name:   gateway.necthree.com
Address: 10.222.190.129

Comment: However,when i tried dig command it showed the ipv6 IP

Comment: It looks like your bind configuration is working but nslookup prefers/unable to do dns6 lookups.

Comment: Nslookup uses it's own libraries, dig uses the default resolver - you should be good unless you need nslookup to be able to look it up for whatever reason. Nslookup is an old tool, and while it isn't officially deprecated, most people prefer dig when available. If you are using nslookup in a script or something for monitoring, consider using dig instead.

Comment: @Sam `nslookup` does A lookups by default. There is a way to make it do AAAA lookups, but I don't remember how. I use `dig` when I need AAAA lookups.